# What is the difference between __global__ and __host__ __device__?

Tags: cuda, gpu

What is the difference between the following two declarations?

```
__host__ __device__ void my_kernel(float* input, float* output, int size) 
{
  // code to be executed by each thread in parallel
}
```

```
__global__ void my_kernel(float* input, float* output, int size) 
{
  // code to be executed by each thread in parallel
}
```

As far as I understand, two copies of the same routine are created and executed in the first case.

How is the second case different from the first case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [programming guide defines them](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-execution-space-specifiers)

`__global__` is used to decorate a [kernel](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#kernels) definition in CUDA.  A kernel is a function that will be auto-parallelized across multiple threads, as part of the kernel launch process.  So a kernel launch requires a special handling like:

```
my_kernel<<<...>>>(...);
```

it would typically be "launched" like that in host code, but specifies execution on the device (host == CPU, device == GPU)

`__host__` is used to decorate an ordinary C++ style function that is callable from host code (and runs on the host processor).

`__device__` is used to decorate an ordinary C++ style function that is callable from device code and runs on the device processor (i.e. callable from a thread in a kernel, or another `__device__` function.)

A function definition can have both `__host__` and `__device__` decorations, in which case a function will be compiled for the host, and another function of the same prototype will be compiled for the device.  neither `__host__` nor `__device__` is used for decorating a kernel function, however.